# Rerender view causes errors

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-app-kit

I'd like to change the layout of my page when I click anywhere in the page.
Basically what I did, into my application view, I created a function that changes the layoutName, then rerender the view.

**application.js (view)**

```
export default Ember.View.extend({
    layoutName: 'application-layout1',
    click: function () {
        this.set('layoutName', 'application-layout2');
        this.rerender();
    }
});
```

**application.hbs**

```
{{outlet}}
```

**application-layout1.hbs**

```
Layout 1 header
{{yield}}
Layout 1 footer
```

**application-layout2.hbs**

```
Layout 2 header
{{yield}}
Layout 2 footer
```

It works fine, but I get some errors coming from Ember depending of the page I'm in.

From page 1, when I click, I get this:

> Assertion Failed: Attempted to register a view with an id already in
>   use: null

From page 2:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null

Do you have any idea from where those errors are coming?
Thanks

Comment: I had a similar problem and tried to recreate it in a [JSBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/keyaja/2/) but it works fine there. I get an error about a missing contextualElement on rerender in my real app, though.